# How to get past "java-lang-runtime exception an-error-occured-while-executing-doinbackground " error?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, github-api, retrofit

Hi I'm trying to create an android app to interact with Github Api.
I am using Retrofit library to do that, when i tried a simple example with ASyncTask i get

> AsyncTask Fatal Exception

error,i think I'm doing things properly here can't understand what's missing or wrong
can't understand why, please help !

Code Sample:

```
private class Process extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>
    {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            RestAdapter restAdapter;
            String url= params[0];
            restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(url)
            .build();


        // Create an instance of our GitHub API interface.
         GitHub github = restAdapter.create(GitHub.class);

        // Fetch and print a list of the contributors to this library.
        List<Contributor> contributors = github.contributors("square", "retrofit");

       return contributors.toString();

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            text.setText(result);
        }

    }
```

Here is the Error Log:

```
09-02 07:32:55.132: E/AndroidRuntime(2830): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
09-02 07:32:55.132: E/AndroidRuntime(2830): Process: com.example.codemymobile, PID: 2830
09-02 07:32:55.132: E/AndroidRuntime(2830): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
09-02 07:32:55.132: E/AndroidRuntime(2830):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
09-02 07:32:55.132: E/AndroidRuntime(2830):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
09-02 07:32:55.132: E/AndroidRuntime(2830):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
09-02 07:32:55.132: E/AndroidRuntime(2830):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
09-02 07:32:55.132: E/AndroidRuntime(2830):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
09-02 07:32:55.132: E/AndroidRuntime(2830):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
09-02 07:32:55.132: E/AndroidRuntime(2830):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
09-02 07:32:55.132: E/AndroidRuntime(2830):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
09-02 07:32:55.132: E/AndroidRuntime(2830): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: retrofit.RestAdapter$Builder
09-02 07:32:55.132: E/AndroidRuntime(2830):     at com.example.codemymobile.MainActivity$Process.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:50)
09-02 07:32:55.132: E/AndroidRuntime(2830):     at com.example.codemymobile.MainActivity$Process.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
09-02 07:32:55.132: E/AndroidRuntime(2830):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
09-02 07:32:55.132: E/AndroidRuntime(2830):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
09-02 07:32:55.132: E/AndroidRuntime(2830):     ... 4 more
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: retrofit.RestAdapter$Builder`

Comment: What does it mean ?  retrofit library is missing or something ? I added retrofit library to the project !

Comment: May be not added properly. Try adding again, clean build, and run again.

Comment: Just tried it , Still no luck :/ .. any other suggestion ?

Comment: @Dhruti - or can you suggest me any other Rest library for android ?

Comment: Relocate these lines of code to onPost because you should not update any UI code in doInBackground() //Create an instance of our GitHub API interface.
         GitHub github = restAdapter.create(GitHub.class);

        // Fetch and print a list of the contributors to this library.
        List<Contributor> contributors = github.contributors("square", "retrofit");